# Checking if String is Palindrome (using char[] input rather than string)

Tags: java, string, palindrome, arrays

I am aware of the solution to this problem:

```
bool isPalindrome(string s) {
  int n = s.length();
  for (int i=0;i<(n / 2) + 1;++i) {
     if (s.charAt(i) != s.charAt(n - i - 1)) {
         return false;
     }
  }

  return true;
}
```

However I am wondering how this solution would be changed to work out if a string is a palindrome using `char[]` as input rather than a `string`? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "char as input"?

Answer (score 1):

If all you get is a `char`, it's trivially a palindrome since it's inherently of length one.

If you get a `char[]` (an *array* of `char`s), it'll use the exact same logic as the above, but with array methods instead of String methods. So `.length()` becomes `.length`, `s.charAt(i)` becomes `s[i]`, and so forth.

Or did you mean something else? It's a pretty vague question...

Comment: Yes i meant a char[] array sorry

Answer (score 0):

I think it would look something like this (in Java now)

```
// boolean - not bool.
public static boolean isPalindrome(char[] s) {
  int n = s.length;                      // get the array length.
  for (int i = 0; i < (n / 2) + 1; ++i) {
    if (s[i] != s[n - i - 1]) {          // access the characters at their positions.
      return false;
    }
  }
  // must be a palindrome.
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Although this is Java, not C.

Comment: oops. shouldn't that have been a `boolean` then OP?

Comment: Yes, the OP is not using correct syntax either.

Comment: Thanks for ur answers, Java is the language i am looking for, sorry I forgot to add that the original is in C. Is the answer posted here correct for Java?

Comment: Yes. And very nearly the same as my answer was in C++.